# Come down a mountain or come down from a mountain?

Tags: sentence-meaning, difference

When somebody is descending from the slopes of a mountain which is the correct way to say this:

They're coming down a mountain (bridge, hill).

or

They're coming down from a mountain (bridge, hill) ?

If both are correct, how do you explain the difference?

Comment: Why do you think  that either of them is wrong?

Comment: Neither version is incorrect. _Coming down a mountain_ is the action of descending the slope; if someone has _come down from_ a mountain, they have been to the summit and come back. We usually speak of coming _over_ a bridge.

Comment: In practice it makes little or no *semantic* difference whether you include the preposition or not with your exact example. It's just a matter of the *syntactic* relationship between the verb *(**to come down**)* and the associated "object" *(**a mountain**)*. But it ***could*** make a difference in similar contexts. With no preposition, that "object" specifies where the specified action is ***currently taking place***, but if ***from*** is included it might simply identify ***where the action started***. Compare *They're coming **down from Scotland*** and ***... down the M1 motorway.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "from" is implying a source of the movement. The "coming" is indicating a destination.

"Coming down a mountain" means that the person is on the mountain, moving downwards, and coming towards some implied destination.

"Coming down from a mountain" means the person is on the mountain, moving downwards, and moving away from presumably the pinnacle.

Answer (score 1):

I think both forms are used.

Definition of **come down from**

1: to move or fall downward from (somewhere or something):

> I'd like you to come down from that ledge before you fall down.

2: to be passed on from (a former time):

> This is a story that has come down from ancient times.

3: informal : to stop feeling the effect of (an illegal drug): to stop being high on (a drug)

> an addict who is coming down from heroin

[Reference](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come%20down%20from)

Answer (score 1):

When put forth as “coming down from The mountain”
(as opposed to A mountain, any mountain) there is a connotation of epic transformation.

Coming down from the mountain carries the message of humbling and seeking atonement.

Coming down from a high and haughty place.
A lonely place.
Back to community and communal responsibility.

Coming down from a place measured by lofty ambitions, personal dreams, self-oriented exploration,
(from up there) back down to earth, so to speak.

A coming down from “alonement” to atonement.